# Create cart for session via SOAP

Tags: product, cart, session

**Info**

I'm quite new to Magento and now I've to develop an external service (C# web service), which needs to add a product to a customers cart (using the SOAPv2 call `shoppingCartProductAdd`). The only information I got is the **encrypted customer session id** and the **quote id** (if the customer has already a cart).

**Problem**

If I've the qoute id (cart id), everything works just fine. Without the qoute id the product can't be added of course.

**Question(s)**

Is it possible to create a cart for a session? Yes I've already seen the method `shoppingCartCreate`, but this will only create a cart and doesn't connect it with the customer session. Is there a method for connecting the a cart with a session?

Comment: I have created cart using "cart.create" and then assinged to customer using "cart_customer.set".
but this will only create a cart on "LocalHost" and doesn't connect it with the customer session on "Live Website". Is there something that am i missing for cart sync?

Answer (score 1):

The Magento SOAP API is a **web-service** and is meant for **data exchange** with external systems such as ERP, accounting, etc.
You can create orders via SOAP-API in your shop which you will see afterwards in the customers account as well as in the shop admin-interface.

You are trying to fill a customers shopping cart with products from the SOAP API which is not a standard function.

I've never set it up like this, but what you need to do to achieve your goal is, to create a connection between your visitors/customers session in the browser and the shopping cart.

Depending on your intended usage you'll need to access the visitors', customers' and checkout session:

Get the visitor session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
```

Get the customer session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

Get the checkout session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

Set customers session to checkout session:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
    ->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
```

Whatever you do: Be careful with setting, storing,... the session-id via URL and cookies.
This *can* be a potentical security issue.